# Have a wpf window inside another wpf window

Tags: wpf, window

Is there a way to host a WPF window inside another WPF window. I have a couple of somewhat complex forms in place. But now to simplify things I am trying to merge a few of them as tabpages inside one 'Dashboard' form.

Please note that I am not trying to host a Windows Form, but another WPF window

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want tabpages, why not use a TabControl with UserControls inside ? If you need to transform one of these tabs to a floating window, just put the UserControl in a new Window...

Comment: I am already using a TabControl. But instead of hosting a UserControl, I'd like to host an already existing Window. Is that possible?

Comment: no it's not... you have to change your window to a UserControl

Answer (score 2):

Can I answer this question with another question; why would you not create them as controls rather than other WPF windows, that you want to host in the main WPF window?

Comment: I guess that's because he wants to take advantage of the default window behavior (title bar to move it, close/min/max buttons...)

Comment: Not really Thomas. I don't care about having any of those things. Is it possible to convert an existing Window into a User Control? What I'm really trying to do is to save time and use existing Windows which are already running (and have been tested in production) within a new "Main" Window. Each of the existing Window will just become a tab within this "Main" window instead of being a separate window.

Answer (score 2):

a bit late on this, but I guess with WindowsForms interop you can put in WPF a WinForms control host and in that host put a WinForms control that hosts the handle of a WPF window

Comment: >hosts the handle of a WPF window

Any elaboration?

Comment: you can make WinForms controls from what I remember that wrap a window handle. So since you can get the window handle of a WPF window, you could wrap it with a WinForms control I believe. Then since WPF can host WinForms controls via interop layer it has (vice-versa also is available from what I remember), you could put that WinForms wrapper of that WPF window inside another WPF window

Comment: btw, I'd make them inherit from UserControl instead which is more versatile (e.g. could have Windows that host that UserControl and also could have another layout with a tabbed view that hosts at each tab one of those UserControls)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking for is MDI, Multiple Document Interface. Something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/mwiwpf.aspx) might help.

Do note, however, that the MDI paradigm is largely shunned these days. There are usually better ways to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Cool... however the chrome for the child windows is quite ugly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to hosting contents of WPF Window1.xaml (page1.xaml) inside within another WPF Window.

Well...you can use Navigation. Instead running window1.xaml contents inside tab then you can work with your data inside Navigation. Navigation can run within WPF Window Application. You just design your form / UI in page1.xaml.

one another..MDI old and rusty. We want clear of top window nowadays.