# Display a WPF window inside another

Tags: wpf, mdi

Before pointing me to [Have a wpf window inside another wpf window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287820/have-a-wpf-window-inside-another-wpf-window)
or telling me that MDI is soooo 1995, let me explain my application.

I'm creating a MessageBanner window that works similar to the message banner we see in several sites nowadays (including SO)

I want client code to call my message banner using four different modes:

```
MessageBanner.Show(content);
MessageBanner.Show(content, ownerWindow);
MessageBanner.ShowModal(content);
MessageBanner.ShowModal(content, ownerWindow);
```

I believe you got the application.

The thing is that when ownerWindow is displayed, I want to display my MessageBanner window inside the ownerWindow.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: MDI was completely obsolete *by* 1995, when Windows 95 came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to add it as a Window. It sounds to me like you'd want to create it as an adorner rather than a window.

Comment: That's the direction I took yesterday. The problem it will only work in hosting windows that have an adorner, but I think that's reasonable to ask.