# Add a xaml File in a main tabbed Window

Tags: c#, wpf, mdi, tabbed-interface

I'm trying to create a application with tabbed interface. For now I have this kind of interface
[image]

with this code

```
<Window x:Class="BMG.BackOffice.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    Title="MainWindow" Height="572" Width="776">

<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock>
                tab1
            </TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Label>Test for tab1</Label>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock>
                tab2
            </TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock>
                tab3
            </TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Header>            
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock>
              tab4
            </TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I have already write other windows and I wonder if is it possible to "insert" these windows in the tabs (a window for a tab). So to replace `<Label>Test for tab1</Label>`
by a window (.xaml file)

Thanks for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would convert those window controls to UserControls and then embed those inside the TabItems.

```
<TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock>
                tab1
            </TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <MyUserControl />
</TabItem>
```

I don't know if you can have a window inside another window but reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287820/have-a-wpf-window-inside-another-wpf-window) question Thomas Levesque says that one can't have another window inside a tabitem.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the Window and get its `Content` property since a Window itself cannot be the child of another control.

I should note that this is *very messy*, the best solution is probably to turn the **content** of the Window into a UserControl, that way you can use it in the Window and the TabControl, once could call that composite UI refactoring i guess.