# Placing a window inside a window

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

Is it possible in WPF to treat a window as if it was a control?
for example: add a window to a grid or to the children of another control?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The short answer is no.
Please look at the following [post][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287820/have-a-wpf-window-inside-another-wpf-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Close, Minimise and Maximize Buttons are not important, I think this can be simply done by declaring:

```
FrameWorkElement content  = yourWindow.Content
```

and adding `content` to a Grid or ....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for **MDI** or **Multiple Document Interface**. 
You can check this out:

- [Multiple Window Interface for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22927/Multiple-Window-Interface-for-WPF)
- [WPF MDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: A bit late, but I only submitted the code today : here is another option : http://mongoose.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve from this? If you want a multi screen application without creating a new window, you can create UserControls and load them on the fly.